# Three.js - get terrain height (position.y) of the mesh at specific position.x,z - without mouse and raycaster?

Tags: three.js, game-physics, blender

Let's say I have a sort of rather simple terrain from Blender exported as GLB object, which is a Group and contains a Mesh with BufferGeometry. I have another GLB object which is a model of vehicle. How can I read proper position.y at specific x,z locations (idealy 4 locations for setting car position and rotation) without moving mouse and using raycaster? I need to know what is elevation and height at specific region. Any simple clue without game-physics engine on top of ThreeJS?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a Raycaster. I don't know why you don't want to use it, it's the easiest way to find an intersection without a physics engine and without tons of math.

Simply use [`Raycaster.set()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.ray) to point straight down from your XZ coords and see where it intersects the terrain:

```js
var ray = new THREE.Raycaster();
var rayPos = new THREE.Vector3();

// Use y = 100 to ensure ray starts above terran
rayPos.set(x, 100, z);
var rayDir = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0); // Ray points down

// Set ray from pos, pointing down
ray.set(rayPos, rayDir);

// Check where it intersects terrain Mesh
let intersect = ray.intersectObject(terrainMesh);
console.log(intersect);
```

[See here for the `intersect` object](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster.intersectObject). It includes the `point` in space where the intersection takes place.

Comment: Works great, thank you! In my case Mesh has children so I use: ray.intersectObject(terrainMesh, true); and I am looking for intersect[ 0 ].point.y when intersect.length > 0